# Which file do I need to modify my.cnf MariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb, configuration, mariadb-10.1

I want to modify these values:

```
[mysqld]
key_buffer_size    = 256M
max_allowed_packet  = 128M
thread_stack    = 256K
query_cache_limit  = 64M
query_cache_size        = 384M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1073741824
thread_cache_size = 256
back_log = 256
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
```

I've tried to edit the files that MariaDB says:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

But none of them seems to apply changes.

I'm running last version of MariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04 
(10.1.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

I've checked Stack Overflow before asking, including [How do I find the MySQL my.cnf location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location/2485758#2485758)

Comment: Are your cnf files pulling in other cnf files that may be overwriting the changes you made?

Comment: See if there is already some kind of "include" at the end of `/etc/my.cnf`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but rectified it by adding the following line to /etc/mysql/my.cnf

!include /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf

This seemed to fix the issue of the mariadb config file not being read.

Answer (score 1):

[Configuring MariaDB with my.cnf](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/)

> When `SYSCONFDIR` is not defined (for example, in binary tarballs and DEB packages)
>
> ```
> Location             | Scope
> ---------------------+--------
> /etc/my.cnf          | Global
> /etc/mysql/my.cnf    | Global
> $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf   | Server
> defaults-extra-file  | File specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any
> ~/.my.cnf            | User
> ```
>
> When `SYSCONFDIR` is defined (for example, in RPM packages it is /etc)
>
> ```
> Location            |  Scope
> --------------------+---------
> SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf   |  Global
> $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf  |  Server
> defaults-extra-file |  File specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any
> ~/.my.cnf           |  User
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you had restarted your server.

You must restart your server after changes are made, or it won't read the variables.  If you're using **systemd** it's:

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

Or if you're using **sysV** it's:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

... Also you must be sure that the server restarts, as it can die if the options files are messed up.  The way I normally test this is with something like:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Which should give you a

```
mysql>
```

prompt.  Hit quit to end this tool.