# what's `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf` used for? (i.e. `my.cnf` vs `mariadb.cnf`)

Tags: my.cnf

I'm trying to better understand how MariaDB is configured.

From `mysqld --help --verbose` I can see that my mariadb server daemon uses `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

But I'm curious about the **`/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf`** file, and what it's intended for?  It has almost nothing in it compared to my.cnf.

---

The package **mysql-common** installs **my.cnf**
The package **mariadb-common** installs **mariadb.cnf**

---

On my Debian Buster system `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf` are similar in what they 'include'.

One minor difference is that because `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf` already includes `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d`, `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf` seems to include `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d` twice.

`my.cnf` is full of options, and
`mariadb.cnf` has little to no content, so doesn't appear to be a replacement to my.cnf, at least not yet.

---

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf               --!includedir--> conf.d
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf --!includedir--> mariadb.conf.d
    /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
    ...
```

---

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf           --!includedir-->  conf.d  AND  mariadb.conf.d
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf  --!includedir--> mariadb.conf.d
    /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

  /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/         (duplicate load)
    ...
```

---

Comment: I **think** it's just to give you an extra options file `--include-dir`- I searched myself and even on the MariaDB site, there appears to be [nothing](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/) - the only thing that I could find of any interest was [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216659/which-file-do-i-need-to-modify-my-cnf-mariadb-on-ubuntu-18-04). p.s. +1 for a well written, and researched first question - if only they all could be like this! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu server 20.04 `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is a symlink pointing to `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`, which in turn is a symlink pointing to `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf`.

I could be wrong, but it seems like the my.cnf file's existence is just to keep backwards compatibility with MySQL and is intended to be phased out over time.